# How to write the output of the dataframe into CSV file in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on regression classification algorithm using pyspark. I would like to save model output into a CSV file. I have used

```
dataframe.savaAstextFile('hdfs://a/b/x')
```

but it throws an error stating saveAstextFile attribute not in the list. Please see the below code and advise:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, PipelineModel
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier as RF
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorIndexer, VectorAssembler, SQLTransformer
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator, BinaryClassificationEvaluator
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import BinaryClassificationMetrics as metric
from pyspark.ml.tuning import CrossValidator, ParamGridBuilder
import pandas
import numpy as np
#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoder
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, accuracy_score, adjusted_rand_score, roc_auc_score

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

inData = sc.textFile("hdfs://ML_test_data/train2.csv")
header = inData.first()

fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in header.split(',')]

fields[0].dataType = IntegerType()
fields[4].dataType = IntegerType()
fields[7].dataType = IntegerType()
fields[8].dataType = IntegerType()
#fields[9].dataType = IntegerType()
#fields[10].dataType = StructType()
fields[11].dataType = IntegerType()

schema = StructType(fields)

actualData = inData.filter(lambda x: x != header)

data_temp = actualData.map(lambda x:x.split(',')).map(lambda p:(int(p[0]),p[1], p[2], p[3], int(p[4]),
                                                             p[5], p[6], int(p[7]), int(p[8]), p[9], p[10], int(p[11])))

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data_temp, schema)
print (df.dtypes)
'''
df.createOrReplaceTempView("testTab")
result_df = sqlContext.sql("select Product_Category_2 from testTab ")
print (result_df.show)

result_collect = result_df.collect()
for i in result_collect:
    avg_prod_cat2 = i
    print ("avg_prod_cat2",avg_prod_cat2 )

'''

def prodCat2(originalCol):

     if originalCol == '':
         return '2'
     else:

         return originalCol

udfValProdCt2 = udf(prodCat2, StringType())
df = df.withColumn("prod_cat2", udfValProdCt2("Product_Category_2"))
df = df.withColumn("prod_cat3", udfValProdCt2("Product_Category_3") )
print (df.dtypes)
df = df.drop("Product_Category_2")
df = df.drop("Product_Category_3")
print (df.dtypes)
print (df.show)
#p_df = df.toPandas()
#print (p_df.head(15))

column_vec_in = ['User_ID', 'Product_ID', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Occupation', 'City_Category', 'Stay_In_Current_City_Years', 'Marital_Status',
              'Product_Category_1', 'Purchase', 'prod_cat2', 'prod_cat3']
column_vec_out = ['User_ID_catVec', 'Product_ID_catVec', 'Gender_catVec', 'Age_catVec', 'Occupation_catVec', 'City_Category_catVec',
                  'Stay_In_Current_City_Years_catVec', 'Marital_Status_catVec', 'Product_Category_1_catVec',
                  'Purchase_catVec', 'prod_cat2_catVec', 'prod_cat3_catVec']

indexers = [StringIndexer(inputCol=x, outputCol=x +'_tmp') for x in column_vec_in]

encoders = [OneHotEncoder(dropLast=False, inputCol=x+'_tmp', outputCol=y) for x,y in zip(column_vec_in, column_vec_out)]

tmp = [[i,j] for i, j in zip(indexers, encoders)]
tmp = [i for sublist in tmp for i in sublist]

cols_now = ['Product_ID_catVec', 'Gender_catVec', 'Age_catVec', 'Occupation_catVec', 'City_Category_catVec',
            'Stay_In_Current_City_Years_catVec', 'Product_Category_1', 'Purchase', 'prod_cat2_catVec', 'prod_cat3_catVec']
assembler_features = VectorAssembler(inputCols=cols_now, outputCol='features')
labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='Purchase', outputCol="label")
tmp += [assembler_features, labelIndexer]

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=tmp)

pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(df)

allData = pipelineModel.transform(df)

allData.cache()
trainingData, testData  = allData.randomSplit([0.7,0.3], seed=4)
print (trainingData.count())
print(testData.count())

rf = RF(labelCol='label', featuresCol='features', numTrees=20)

rfModel= rf.fit(trainingData)
#print("Coefficients : \n" + str(rfModel.coefficientMatrix))
predictions = rfModel.transform(testData)

predictions.printSchema()

result = predictions.select('User_ID', 'Product_ID', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Occupation', 'City_Category', 'Stay_In_Current_City_Years', 'Marital_Status',
              'Product_Category_1', 'Purchase', 'prod_cat2', 'prod_cat3', 'label', 'probability', 'prediction').collect()

result.saveAsTextFile()

for row in result:
    print("User_ID= %s, Product_id= %s -> prob= %s, prediction= %s"  %(row.User_ID, row.Product_ID, row.probability, row.prediction))
```

Appreciate your quick help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have already found the perfect solution, however let me write a short code to write and read pyspark Dataframes

this is a short code to create dataframe

```
x = [1,2,3,4] 
y = [0,1,0,1]
df = sc.parallelize([x,y]).toDF(['A', 'B','C','D'])
```

## Spark 2.2.X

write dataframe to csv

```
df.write.csv('/tmp/out')
```

read csv to dataframe

```
newdf = spark.read.csv("/tmp/out")
```

Comment: can you help  me: i use `df.repartition(1).write.mode(mode).csv(hdfs_path)` and still save as  parquet